# Conan workspace equivalent for dotnet/nuget?

Tags: .net, package, nuget-package, conan

I am coming from c++ world with conan packages and conan workspaces and I was wondering, if there is any equivalent for dotnet/nuget packaging?

And if not, what would be alternative workflows to develop multiple dependent projects/packages at once?

Answer (score 0):

You put the projects in a solution, with references between them as `ProjectReference`.

Then when you run `dotnet pack` those references are automatically converted to `PackageReference`, and you get one NuGet package per project